# groovy/grails domain class create new instance takes to much time

Tags: performance, grails, object, groovy, instance

my code looks like:

```
static Value findValue(ProjectTouchpoint touchpoint, ProjectQualifier qualifier, ProjectTargetGroup targetGroup)
    {
        def value = Value.findByProjecttouchpointAndProjectqualifierAndProjecttargetgroup(touchpoint,qualifier,targetGroup)
        if(!value) {
            value = new Value(projecttouchpoint:touchpoint, projectqualifier:qualifier, projecttargetgroup:targetGroup, value:0)
              value.save(flush:true)
        }
        return value;
    }
```

problem:
this line of code takes about 1 seconds to execute:

```
value = new Value(projecttouchpoint:touchpoint, projectqualifier:qualifier, projecttargetgroup:targetGroup, value:0)
```

i create just a new instance of a domain class,  the value.save(flush:true) takes just 0.X seconds (DB write)

i init about 10k values in a loop and it takes to much time

any ideas? ty

Comment: I think we will need to see Value to have any suggestions on what is wrong here. Otherwise I suggest using a profiler for further hints

Answer (score 0):

Doing the loop in a `withTransaction` block should help

Here's a [blog post](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2009/09/09/batch-processing-in-grails/) from a few years ago showing the idea